# Insertion operator not producing the expected output?

Tags: c++

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    cout<<"Hellow World"<<endl;
    cout.operator<<("Hellow World");
    cout.operator<<(endl);
}
```

I know that `cout<<"Hellow World"<<endl;` is interpreted as
 `cout.operator<<("Hellow World");`
But this code is producing the following results

`Hellow World`

`0x8048830`

if i use `operator<<(cout,"Hellow World");` works fine 
what is the difference between  `cout.operator<<("Hellow World");` and
`operator<<(cout,"Hellow World");`

Comment: The assumption in your first paragraph is incorrect. Don't assume that an operator is a member of a class

Comment: [don't use `endl` unless you know and really need its behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/995714)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::basic_ostream` overloads `operator<<` in two groups, [members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and [non-members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

The difference is due to the fact that when you write `cout<<"Hellow World"<<endl;` the non-member overload of `const char*` is chosen to print the string literal.

When you call the member version, the best fit is only the `void*` overload.

Comment: `0x8048830` is this undefined value or it is something that is related to a void pointer

Comment: `cout.operator<<((char*)"Hellow World");` even this produces the same result `0x8048830`

Comment: @Anjaneyulu - It's the address of the string literal. And casting to `char*` won't make a difference. You take the `const char*` overload out of the picture the moment you call the member overload directly.

Answer (score 9):

> what is the difference between `cout.operator<<("Hellow World");` and
>   `operator<<(cout, "Hellow World")`;

When you write `cout.operator<<("Hellow World");` you are calling the `operator<<` method and passing a `const char *`. Because this method is not overloaded to take a `const char *`, but is overloaded to take a `const void *`, that's the one you call and get `0x8048830` (which is the address of the `'H'` character in your string).

When you write `operator<<(cout, "Hellow World")` you are calling a free function `operator<<` that takes an output stream on the left-hand side and a `const char *` on the right-hand side. There happens to exist such a function, and it has the following declaration *(simplified)*:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char *s);
```

And so you get printed the sequence of characters that begin at `s`, and end at the first `'\0'` that is encountered (so you get `Hellow, world`).

Finally, when you write `std::cout << "Hello, world" << std::endl;`, since you are passing a `const char *` to `operator<<`, the free function, being a perfect match, is chosen over the method `operator<<`.